# (100.0/3.0)*3 == 100, but using variables yields 99.99996. What's the deal?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am aware of the inherent imprecision of floats. What I'm confused about is why I would get returned "100" from something I would expect to resolve 0.99999999 etc. How could 0.33*3 ever possibly yield 100?

Here is my code: if I say

```
float x = 100.0/3.0;
printf("%f",x*3.0);
```

The output is "99.999996". Yet if I say

```
printf("%f",(100.0/3)*3);
```

The output is "100". Shouldn't they be identical? I would expect `x` to resolve to (100.0/3.0), exactly what's written there in plaintext -- yet they yield two different results.

Comment: [Gently click me](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), or him ↓.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @WiSaGaN I'm not the downvoter, but probably because it was asked O(∞) times and the OP doesn't show any efforts finding the duplicate.

Comment: @WiSaGaN I did not downvote it but it definite is duplicate

Comment: @JBL To clarify, I *am* aware of the inherent imprecision of floats. What I'm confused about is why I would get returned "100" from something I would expect to resolve 0.99999999 etc. How could 0.33*3 ever possibly yield 100?

Comment: Ok, floating has a rounding error, but I think his question is, why isn't the second code giving the same error? as it is basicly the same equation.

Comment: I do wish people here would stop pointing inexperienced users towards *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*. It's far too advanced for such users, the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is a much better starting point.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin It's not. Types involved are different.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The problem here is not the rounding-error. Such a shame.

Comment: @JBL: It's probably better if you get in the habit of reading the question instead of reflexively linking to Goldberg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your second expression is not equivalent to the first one: it uses `doubles` throughout, while the first one has a conversion to `float` after the division, forcing the intermediate result to lower precision.

To build a fully equivalent expression, add a cast to `float` after division, like this:

```
printf("%f", ((float)(100.0/3.0))*3.0);
//             ^^^^^
```

This produces the same output as your first example, i.e. `"99.999996` ([demo](http://ideone.com/Sha6Yn))

If you use `double` for `x` in your first example, you get the output `100.000000`, too:

```
double x = 100.0/3.0;
printf("%f",x*3.0);
```

([another demo](http://ideone.com/lK9pU5)).